# jquery validation not working on HTML select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had used this jquery validation previously, never encountered a problem before. But on this particular case validation is not done. The ajax code in the submithandler is working even if an option is not selected. This jquery plugin is working fine in another form on the same page itself. I copy pasted this dropdown on that form and it worked. Is there something else to keep in mind while using this plugin? Or is it a syntax error?

```
<table>
        <hr>
            <form  id="statuschange" class="reg-page" >
                <tr style="width:100%"> 
                    <td style="width:20%">                                                          
                        <strong>Change Status:</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:10%"></td>                                         
                    <td style="width:50%">
                        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></span>
                            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenid" name="hiddenid" value={{.LeadId}}>
                            <select id="changeprocess" name="changeprocess" class="form-control">
                                <option disabled selected>Choose Process</option>
                                {{range .Process}}
                                    <option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>
                                {{end}} 
                            </select>
                        </div>                                                                      
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20%">                                                          
                        <button class="btn-u btn-block pull-right" type="submit">Change</button>
                    </td>                                                                                                   
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
```

My javascript is as follows:-

```
$("#statuschange").validate({
            rules: {
                changeprocess:"required"                    
            },
            messages: {
                changeprocess: "Please choose from dropdown"
            },
            submitHandler: function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '/changestatus',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data : { changeprocess: $('#changeprocess').val(),hiddenid: $('#hiddenid').val()},
                    success : function(data) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: invalid markup. Table can't have form as a direct child but you can put that in the td.

Comment: @Jai Post this as an answer. It worked. Thanks man.

Comment: posted, Glad if that solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seemed to me is the structure of the markup, which is in a way is invalid. As `table` element can't have a `hr/form` as a direct child other than `tbody`.

So you can put the `table` inside `form` element.

```html
<form id="statuschange" class="reg-page">
  <table>
    <tr style="width:100%">
      <td style="width:20%">
        <strong>Change Status:</strong>
      </td>
      <td style="width:10%"></td>
      <td style="width:50%">
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></span>
          <input type="hidden" id="hiddenid" name="hiddenid" value={{.LeadId}}>
          <select id="changeprocess" name="changeprocess" class="form-control">
            <option disabled selected>Choose Process</option>
            {{range .Process}}
            <option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>
            {{end}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:20%">
        <button class="btn-u btn-block pull-right" type="submit">Change</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using the value attribute for the default option, its text is considered as its value

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose Process</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use required .

```
<select id="changeprocess" name="changeprocess" required>
    <option value="" hidden="hidden">Choose Process</option>
    {{range .Process}}
    <option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>
    {{end}} 
</select>
```

Comment: then what is `changeprocess:"required"`